# Clever way to find zero remainder with decreasing divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

I need to factorize a number starting from an initial divisor and going down by $1$ at each step. For example, starting from $99$ and decreasing it one by one

$$9779 = 99 \times 98 + 77$$
$$9779 = 98 \times 99 + 77$$
$$9779 = 97 \times 100 + 79$$
$$\vdots$$
$$9779 = 77 \times 127 + 0$$

I reach the zero remainder after $23$ steps.

I was wondering if there is a clever way to "predict" the first null remainder given the first division(s). I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715580/find-the-next-divisor-without-remainder) but mine has a particular pattern so maybe there is a better solution than brute force.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you can certainly jump two each time if looking for factors of an odd number as they'll never be even

Comment: Aren't you just asking for the largest divisor of the number less than 100?

Comment: You could do trial division by only using the primes. If you have completed the factorization, you can easily find all divisors. Knowing that $1001$ is divisible by $7$ and $11$ here gives immediately two prime divisors.

Comment: In the end , it simply depends upon the number you choose as the starting value . If you would have started at $150$ , it would take you $24$ steps to reach to the first divisor , i.e $127.$

Comment: Why do you start with 99?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, in this case I'm looking for the largest 2 factors with 2 digits, that's why I start from 99. I need to apply this to solve a more general problem where I need to find the largest 2 factors with `n` digits each.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Yes, I can use any prime factorization algo but I'm looking for both factors with `n` digits, in this case `n=2`. Probably finding all the prime factors and trying all possible combination will be still more efficient than the proposed "sieve".